# Nifi image Not Running over openshift

Tags: openshift, apache-nifi

While trying to run docker image of **apache nifi** present in the docker hub in the open shift, it is giving me the permission issue as the docker image was running the user **nifi** which is not allowed via openshft. so I build the docker image using the below docker file but now I am not even able to run the build image in my local docker container.

```
    FROM openjdk:8-jre

ARG NIFI_VERSION=1.12.1
ARG BASE_URL=https://archive.apache.org/dist
ARG MIRROR_BASE_URL=${MIRROR_BASE_URL:-${BASE_URL}}
ARG NIFI_BINARY_PATH=${NIFI_BINARY_PATH:-/nifi/${NIFI_VERSION}/nifi-${NIFI_VERSION}-bin.zip}
ARG NIFI_TOOLKIT_BINARY_PATH=${NIFI_TOOLKIT_BINARY_PATH:-/nifi/${NIFI_VERSION}/nifi-toolkit-${NIFI_VERSION}-bin.zip}

ENV NIFI_BASE_DIR=/opt/nifi
ENV NIFI_HOME ${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/nifi-current
ENV NIFI_TOOLKIT_HOME ${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/nifi-toolkit-current

ENV NIFI_PID_DIR=${NIFI_HOME}/run
ENV NIFI_LOG_DIR=${NIFI_HOME}/logs

USER root

ADD sh/ ${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/scripts/

# Setup NiFi user and create necessary directories
RUN mkdir -p ${NIFI_BASE_DIR} \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y jq xmlstarlet procps

# Download, validate, and expand Apache NiFi Toolkit binary.
RUN curl -fSL ${MIRROR_BASE_URL}/${NIFI_TOOLKIT_BINARY_PATH} -o ${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/nifi-toolkit-${NIFI_VERSION}-bin.zip \
    && echo "$(curl ${BASE_URL}/${NIFI_TOOLKIT_BINARY_PATH}.sha256) *${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/nifi-toolkit-${NIFI_VERSION}-bin.zip" | sha256sum -c - \
    && unzip ${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/nifi-toolkit-${NIFI_VERSION}-bin.zip -d ${NIFI_BASE_DIR} \
    && rm ${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/nifi-toolkit-${NIFI_VERSION}-bin.zip \
    && mv ${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/nifi-toolkit-${NIFI_VERSION} ${NIFI_TOOLKIT_HOME} \
    && ln -s ${NIFI_TOOLKIT_HOME} ${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/nifi-toolkit-${NIFI_VERSION} \
    && chmod -R g+rwX ${NIFI_TOOLKIT_HOME}


# Download, validate, and expand Apache NiFi binary.
RUN curl -fSL ${MIRROR_BASE_URL}/${NIFI_BINARY_PATH} -o ${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/nifi-${NIFI_VERSION}-bin.zip \
    && echo "$(curl ${BASE_URL}/${NIFI_BINARY_PATH}.sha256) *${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/nifi-${NIFI_VERSION}-bin.zip" | sha256sum -c - \
    && unzip ${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/nifi-${NIFI_VERSION}-bin.zip -d ${NIFI_BASE_DIR} \
    && rm ${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/nifi-${NIFI_VERSION}-bin.zip \
    && mv ${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/nifi-${NIFI_VERSION} ${NIFI_HOME} \
    && mkdir -p ${NIFI_HOME}/conf \
    && mkdir -p ${NIFI_HOME}/database_repository \
    && mkdir -p ${NIFI_HOME}/flowfile_repository \
    && mkdir -p ${NIFI_HOME}/content_repository \
    && mkdir -p ${NIFI_HOME}/provenance_repository \
    && mkdir -p ${NIFI_HOME}/state \
    && mkdir -p ${NIFI_LOG_DIR} \
    && ln -s ${NIFI_HOME} ${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/nifi-${NIFI_VERSION} \
    && chgrp -R 0 ${NIFI_BASE_DIR} \
    && chmod -R g+rwX ${NIFI_BASE_DIR} \
    && chmod -R g=u ${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/ \
    && chmod -R g=u /etc/passwd
#ADD bootstrap.conf ${NIFI_HOME}/conf/bootstrap.conf

# Clear nifi-env.sh in favour of configuring all environment variables in the Dockerfile
RUN echo "#!/bin/sh\n" > ${NIFI_HOME}/bin/nifi-env.sh

# Web HTTP(s) & Socket Site-to-Site Ports
EXPOSE 8080 8443 10000

WORKDIR ${NIFI_HOME}

USER 1001

# Apply configuration and start NiFi
#
# We need to use the exec form to avoid running our command in a subshell and omitting signals,
# thus being unable to shut down gracefully:
# https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint
#
# Also we need to use relative path, because the exec form does not invoke a command shell,
# thus normal shell processing does not happen:
# https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#exec-form-entrypoint-example
ENTRYPOINT ["../scripts/start.sh"]
```

Getting this error while running in the docker container.

```
replacing target file  /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/nifi.properties
replacing target file  /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/nifi.properties
replacing target file  /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/nifi.properties
replacing target file  /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/nifi.properties
replacing target file  /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/nifi.properties
/opt/nifi/scripts/toolkit.sh: 18: /opt/nifi/scripts/toolkit.sh: cannot create //.nifi-cli.nifi.properties: Permission denied
```

This build is  for the open shift, as the apache nifi user is not working in openshift and giving permission issue while starting the local docker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've passed for the same issue trying to run NIFI on a Openshift, I hope that could help you.
The steps used for me was:

As @JuanD shows, I added the config on openshift:

```
securityContext:
        runAsUser: 1000
```

Further on that I also did:

```
RUN chmod -R g+rw ${NIFI_BASE_DIR} \
    && chmod -R g+rwX ${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/scripts \
    && useradd --shell /bin/bash -u ${UID} -g ${GID} -m nifi
```

Another rearrange that I did was to move the copy files to be executed before this command.

And in order to avoid any unnecessary issue I also added the uid-entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

if ! whoami &> /dev/null; then
  if [ -w /etc/passwd ]; then
    echo "${USER_NAME:-nifi}:x:$(id -u):0:${USER_NAME:-nifi} user:${HOME}:/sbin/nologin" >> /etc/passwd
  fi
fi

exec "$@"
```

The entire dockerfile:

```
ARG IMAGE_NAME=openjdk
ARG IMAGE_TAG=8-jre

FROM ${IMAGE_NAME}:${IMAGE_TAG}

ARG MAINTAINER="Apache NiFi <dev@nifi.apache.org>"
LABEL maintainer="${MAINTAINER}"
LABEL site="https://nifi.apache.org"


ARG UID=1000
ARG GID=0
ARG NIFI_VERSION=1.14.0
ARG BASE_URL=https://archive.apache.org/dist
ARG MIRROR_BASE_URL=${MIRROR_BASE_URL:-${BASE_URL}}
ARG NIFI_BINARY_PATH=${NIFI_BINARY_PATH:-/nifi/${NIFI_VERSION}/nifi-${NIFI_VERSION}-bin.zip}
ARG NIFI_TOOLKIT_BINARY_PATH=${NIFI_TOOLKIT_BINARY_PATH:-/nifi/${NIFI_VERSION}/nifi-toolkit-${NIFI_VERSION}-bin.zip}

ENV NIFI_BASE_DIR=/opt/nifi
ENV NIFI_HOME ${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/nifi-current
ENV NIFI_TOOLKIT_HOME ${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/nifi-toolkit-current

ENV NIFI_PID_DIR=${NIFI_HOME}/run
ENV NIFI_LOG_DIR=${NIFI_HOME}/logs

# Download, validate, and expand Apache NiFi Toolkit binary.
RUN mkdir -p ${NIFI_BASE_DIR} \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y jq xmlstarlet procps \
    && curl -fSL ${MIRROR_BASE_URL}/${NIFI_TOOLKIT_BINARY_PATH} -o ${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/nifi-toolkit-${NIFI_VERSION}-bin.zip \
    && echo "$(curl ${BASE_URL}/${NIFI_TOOLKIT_BINARY_PATH}.sha256) *${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/nifi-toolkit-${NIFI_VERSION}-bin.zip" | sha256sum -c - \
    && unzip ${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/nifi-toolkit-${NIFI_VERSION}-bin.zip -d ${NIFI_BASE_DIR} \
    && rm ${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/nifi-toolkit-${NIFI_VERSION}-bin.zip \
    && mv ${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/nifi-toolkit-${NIFI_VERSION} ${NIFI_TOOLKIT_HOME} \
    && ln -s ${NIFI_TOOLKIT_HOME} ${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/nifi-toolkit-${NIFI_VERSION}

# Download, validate, and expand Apache NiFi binary.
RUN curl -fSL ${MIRROR_BASE_URL}/${NIFI_BINARY_PATH} -o ${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/nifi-${NIFI_VERSION}-bin.zip \
    && echo "$(curl ${BASE_URL}/${NIFI_BINARY_PATH}.sha256) *${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/nifi-${NIFI_VERSION}-bin.zip" | sha256sum -c - \
    && unzip ${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/nifi-${NIFI_VERSION}-bin.zip -d ${NIFI_BASE_DIR} \
    && rm ${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/nifi-${NIFI_VERSION}-bin.zip \
    && mv ${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/nifi-${NIFI_VERSION} ${NIFI_HOME} \
    && mkdir -p ${NIFI_HOME}/conf \
    && mkdir -p ${NIFI_HOME}/database_repository \
    && mkdir -p ${NIFI_HOME}/flowfile_repository \
    && mkdir -p ${NIFI_HOME}/content_repository \
    && mkdir -p ${NIFI_HOME}/provenance_repository \
    && mkdir -p ${NIFI_HOME}/state \
    && mkdir -p ${NIFI_LOG_DIR} \
    && ln -s ${NIFI_HOME} ${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/nifi-${NIFI_VERSION}

COPY scripts/ ${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/scripts/

RUN chmod -R g+rw ${NIFI_BASE_DIR} \
    && chmod -R g+rwX ${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/scripts \
    && useradd --shell /bin/bash -u ${UID} -g ${GID} -m nifi

# Clear nifi-env.sh in favour of configuring all environment variables in the Dockerfile
RUN echo "#!/bin/sh\n" > $NIFI_HOME/bin/nifi-env.sh

# Web HTTP(s) & Socket Site-to-Site Ports
EXPOSE 8080 8443 10000 8000

WORKDIR ${NIFI_HOME}

USER ${UID}

ENTRYPOINT [ "../scripts/uid-entrypoint.sh" ]

CMD [ "../scripts/start.sh" ]
```

I hope that could help.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when deploying a custom nifi container to Openshift. Adding this to the deployment.yaml under `spec:` helped:

```
securityContext:
        runAsUser: 1000
        fsGroup: 1000
```

Comment: Getting Error creating: pods "nifi-6-" is forbidden: unable to validate against any security context constraint: [fsGroup: Invalid value: []int64{1000}: 1000 is not an allowed group spec.containers[0].securityContext.securityContext.runAsUser: Invalid value: 1000: must be in the ranges: [1000310000, 1000319999]] and it is not getting up

Comment: Could you please tell me the complete steps you follow and could you please elaborate the custom nifi ..

Comment: I didnt notice in your docker build your switching to user 1001.  Have you tried updating your yaml file to `runAsUser: 1001`?

We customize the Nifi Image with some custom code during the Dccker build.   How are you running the Nifi pod in OpenShift? As a statefulset, deployment, or a plain pod?

Comment: Deploying the image using deploy image dropdown and searching from our repository, which has been uploaded after building the image from the docker file. runAsUser: 1001 this also have tried but the same error  coming in  like 1000